# Monero GUI 2 on tails os text not visible issue

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

On running monero wallet on tails os the text is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run Monero GUI wallet on tails use the 32 bit version.

Open the `start-gui.sh` file. This file is inside the folder where all the monero binaries are.

add this line before the `./monero-wallet-gui` line.

```
export QT_QPA_FONTDIR=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/unifont/
```

This line will provide the path to the fonts folder. Now to run the gui use command:

`bash start-gui.sh`